# How do I set data attribute value by the index of element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple sibling elements, some that are added dynamically and others manually or using JS. Each one has a data attribute of "data-sec_number" with a number value that increases by one for each new element down the page. At the moment I am manually writing these in.
E.g.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=1>
<div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=1></div>
</div>

<div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=2>
<div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=2></div>
</div>

<div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=3>
<div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=3></div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of attribute "data-sec_number" to match the index of the element .resource_sec within the .container element? E.g. the 3rd .resource_sec element will always have a "data-sec_number" value of 3.
I also have the child element of .resource_sec called .sec_number, which has the same data attribute that should mirror the parent.

The JS I have been trying to use is:

```js
var items = $('.container .resource_sec');
var lastItem = $('.container .resource_sec:last');
var index = items.index(lastItem);

$('.resource_sec').attr('data-sec_number', index);
$('.sec_number').attr('data-sec_number', index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=1>
    <div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=1></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=2>
    <div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=2></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row resource_sec" data-sec_number=3>
    <div class="content sec_number" data-sec_number=3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what you want to do, as a **note** `. index()` call return zero-index number, other than that I find you code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of this line

```
$('.resource_sec').attr('data-sec_number', index);
```

is to set the attribute value. to select (query) a specific index please use:

```
$('.resource_sec[data-sec_number=' + index + ']')
```

or

```
$(`.resource_sec[data-sec_number=${index}]`)
```

If you support ES6

---

### UPDATE:

To add a new element in jQuery you may use:

```
var container = $('.container')
var newElement = $('<div class="row resource_sec"></div>').appendTo(container)
```

Then, you can fetch the new element index by passing it to the `index` method,according to Jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

```
var index = container.index(newElement)
```

To append index to the new element attribute:

```
newElement.attr('data-sec_number', index)
```

Comment: Hi, yes I want to set the attribute value. I want to set it to the index of the element. So if a fourth element with class .resource_sec is added, the attribute value (of data-sec_number) for that element's instance will be 4. Thank you!

Comment: @Artistica, again, indexes start from 0.